# Displaying the most relevant advertisements to web users based on their visited pages

Tags: algorithm, web, ads

I am asked to develop a pop-up ad display system for website. What it does is that the website will record the urls that the users visit and display the most relevant pop-up ad for them.

The website administrator first needs to define some groups (e.g. "Golfers", "Video game players") and then define some rules such as:

**If the user visits the url pattern http://www.domain.com/golf-clubs/* and stay on that page for more than 10 seconds, he will be assigned to the Golfers group.**

Also, the website administrator can create ads and assign them to different groups. For example, he can create a golf club promotion ad for users with the **Golfers** group. When the user visits the website again, the system will check if he belongs to any group(s) and display the most relevant ad for him.

For the user identification part, I am going to simply use cookies, which is to assign an unique cookie to every new website visitor.

The difficult part for me is to design the logic about which pop-up ad to display when the user belongs to multiple groups. For example, if he belongs to both **Golfers** and **Video game players** groups. Rather than randomly choosing one to display, is there a better way to handle such situation?

I have come up with a solution that I don't know if it's good or not. That is when a user is assigned a group it also comes with a score for that group. For example, if a user belongs to both **Golfers** and **Video game players** groups but he has a higher score for the **Golfers** group, the system will display a **Golfers** group ad for him as the first priority.

But this creates another difficult problem, how should the group scores calculated for each user? I also need to account for that recent page visits are of more importance, for example, maybe the user was a golfer and belongs to the **Golfers** group with a very high score but he recently visits a lot of video game web pages and gets assigned the **Video game players** group, how many scores should he get in this group?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: have you find something? I think now you can answer you question.

Comment: @Am.rez I still need some time to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is really close to some Operating System problems. For example when it decides about what to keep in cache and what to delete. Both "number" and "time" of visits influence the decision, and of course there are plenty of policies to select.

Here I try to make one in order to show how they work. I want to make it simple and manageable, so I use weights for time `w`and number of visits `v`. For each category, keep number of visits `n` and their relative times `t`. Then calculate sum of weight of time divided by relative times (except the expired ones) plus times of visits multiplied by corresponding weight: `w/t+n*v`. 
Larger `t` leads to smaller score, while larger `n` (number of visits) improves the score.